# Check virtual path with Apache htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several files in `HiddenFiles` folder. I want to check if a file exists in this hidden folder.
If so, display it. Otherwise, return resizer page (`resizer.php`).

Here's what i've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^Virtual([\w\.]+)$ 
RewriteRule  (.*) ../HiddenFiles/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^Virtual([\w\.]+)$ -f
RewriteRule  (.*) ../resizer.php?img=$1
```

Here is my file tree:

```
/
  resizer.php
  HiddenFiles/
    aa.jpg
  VirtualImages/
    .htaccess
```

Example:

- `http://localhost/VirtulaImages/aa.jpg` shows `http://localhost/HiddenFiles/aa.jpg` (because file exists in `HiddenFiles` folder.
- `http://localhost/VirtulaImages/bb.jpg` shows `http://localhost/resizer.php?img=bb.jpg` (because file does not exist in `HiddenFiles` folder).

Comment: In which folder is your htaccess ? Could you provide a simple tree of your folders/files involved ?

Comment: @JustinIurman I creat the map of my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in `/VirtualImages/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/HiddenFiles/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /HiddenFiles/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /resizer.php?img=$1 [L]
```